# Firefox Add-on for Android

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Firefox browser supports add-ons even on Android version. How to develop and distribute Firefox add-on for Android?

Comment: Please checkout [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on developing add-on for Firefox browser. While signing the add-on I saw a tickmark to sign add-on for Android.

I developed extension for desktop browser only but I found that it works the same way for Firefox android too.

All you need to do is take care of responsive ui and build the add-on the same way you would do for a pc browser and while signing add-on don't forget to check android tickbox.

Now to access add-on in android version is bit different from desktop version. Refer to following question for how to access add-on installed in Firefox android version

https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219933/278380

And the accepted answer

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219935/278380